# $ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}\right|-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}-\mu\right|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|y_{i}\right|-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|y_{i}-\mu\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

Let $x=\left(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}\right)$ and $y=\left(y_{1},\cdots,y_{n}\right)$
be arbitrary vectors in $\R^{n}$. Suppose that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}\right|-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}-\mu\right|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|y_{i}\right|-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|y_{i}-\mu\right| & \mbox{for }\forall\mu\in\R.
\end{align*}
Want to show that vector of the ordered $x_{i}$'s
is the same as the vector of the ordered $y_{i}$'s.

Comment: What have you already tried?  Have you considered using $\mu=x_i$ for each $i$?

Comment: Probably best to just assume $x_i\leq x_{i+1}$ and $y_i\leq y_{i+1}$ and assume $x_j<y_j$ for some $j$.

Comment: @abiessu I tried plug that in but I failed to see how it will prove the claim..

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(\mu)=\sum |x_i|-\sum|x_i-\mu|$ and $g(\mu)=\sum |y_i|-\sum|y_i-\mu|$.

Then $f(\mu)$ is differentiable everywhere except when $\mu=x_i$ for some $i$, and $g(\mu)$ is differentiable everywhere except when $\mu=y_i$. But $f(\mu)=g(\mu)$.

You can be more specific: If $\mu\neq x_i$ for all $i$, then 
$$f'(\mu)=|\{i:x_i<\mu\}|-|\{i:x_i>\mu\}|=2|\{i:x_i<\mu\}|-n$$

Similarly for $g'(\mu)$.

Then, for any $\mu$, $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \frac{f'(\mu+\epsilon)-f'(\mu-\epsilon)}{2} = |\{i: x_i=\mu\}|$. So $f'$ entirely determines the set of values, with multiplicity, of the $x_i.$ But $f=g$. So the $y_i$ must be the same multi-set.

Comment: Hi Tom. I don't quite understand your proof. Can you explain the intuition to me a little? Thanks!

Comment: Not if you aren't going to ask a specific question. Do you know what a differentiable function is?

Comment: I am not sure how taking the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ will lead to the desired conclusion..

Comment: It's because the closed form I give for the derivative entirely determines exactly how many $x_i<\mu$, so if the derivatives are equal...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, I am still confused  about how  this will lead to the conclusion that $x_i=y_i$ if the derivatives are equal, then $|{i:x_i<\mu}|=|{i:y_i<\mu}|$ for any $\mu$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You don't have $x_i=y_i$, you only have that some re-ordering of the $x_i$ is the same as $y_i$. I've updated my answer to flesh it out a little further.